# @SerializedName is highlighted in red

Tags: android-studio, gson

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/086TE.jpg)

@SerializedName highlighted in red
The compilation is successful.
Invalidate Caches/restart doesn't help
dependencies are connected
Tell me what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an older version of GSON. To solve your problem, make sure that you're using version 2.8.8.
Add this to your build.gradle,

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8'
```

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, mark this as accepted by clicking on the little tick icon, it may help others too.